# Confusion with comparision opertaor

Tags: javascript, string, numbers, comparison-operators

Please help me understand how this works:

```
"1" > "01" returns true
```

BUT

```
1 > 01 returns false
```

Comment: Well, sorting numbers from A to Z doesn't render intuitive results ;-)

Comment: The answer to `1 === 01` will be useful to you here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

comparison operator always compare value to respective place of operands, so here in the first example

```
  "1" > "01"
   |     ||
   |     ||________________  2nd ( 2nd operand )
   |     __________________  1st ( 2nd operand )
   _________________________ 1st ( 1st operand )
```

so clearly `1 > 0` is true

In second example value is number so leading `0` don't have any significance, so it is actually same as

```
1 > 1 which is clearly false
```

---

JS do not keep the leading zeros before any number

```js
let one = 00001
console.log(one)
console.log(000002)
```

Answer (score 1):

`>` operator will [lexically compare strings,](https://javascript.info/comparison#string-comparison) while it will numerically compare numbers.

And because `1` is greater than `0` it will return true.

This is very similar to comparing `"B"` to `"AB"`:
since `"A"` comes before `"B"`, therefore `"B" > "AB"`

Comment: I'd rephrase--">" will compare whatever is given to it; if it's too strings it will be a lexical comparison, if two numbers, numeric.